# Unable to use while command in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: mysql, batch-file, cmd

What I'm trying to accomplish is dumping each of the databases I have into individual .sql files. Whenever I run my code, I get an error in relation to the 'while' and 'do' commands depending on which one I put first. I've since examples where the 'while' is first and where the 'do' is first. I have tried both and both result in the 'not recognized as an internal or external command.

I'm using the following in my cmd line

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\"mysql -u[user] -p[password] -e "show databases" | while read dbname do "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\"mysqldump -u[user] -p[password] --complete-insert "$dbname" > "D:\Backup\$dbname"_6am_mon.sql; done
```

However, I keep getting the following error: 'while' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Why am I getting an error for using the while and do commands? How do I resolve this error?

Thanks

Comment: The pipe `|`and the output redirection `>` are interpreted by cmd.exe first and not viewed as port of the script. Try to escape them with a caret `^|` and `^>`.

Comment: You also appear to have some strangely placed double quotes.

Comment: @LotPings That resolved the error I was getting. If you create an answer I'll mark it correct.
I do have a side question as a result of solving this question. Am I using the variables correctly? My file is coming out as $dbname_6am_mon.sql instead of the name of the actual database.

Comment: @Compo the quotes were needed because of the spacing in the file path. If I remove the double quotes than I get an error at the spaces.

Comment: I didn't say double quotes weren't needed, I said they were strangely placed. `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql"`, `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump"` and `"D:\Backup\$dbname_6am_mon.sql"` make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe `|` and the output redirection `>` are interpreted by cmd.exe first and not viewed as part of the script. Try to escape them with a caret ^| and ^>

Not knowing much about Mysql script processing the quoting of the redirection file name may be the reason $dbname is not resolved.

A workaround could be to put the script in a file and invoke it from the batch

```
@Echo off
Pushd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\"
mysql -u[user] -p[password] -e "Source X:\Path\Script.sql"
Popd
```